# Pantone gradients methods without causing breakout

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, print-production, overprint

Customer orders a 2 color PMS print. Black and PMS 801 C.

Provided art is a CMYK gradient. Example below.
[image]

In the next example below, converting the gradient to Black and PMS Blue not only looks awful, but also causes breakout in the center area where there is less than 2% ink coverage. This breakout is unacceptable.

[image]

To solve this you can stack a black gradient that does not fall below 2% over the PMS 801 like in the example below.

[image]

The downside to this is when sending a copy to the customer as a PDF it only shows the black layer because there is no Overprint Preview.

[image]

Of course you could rasterize these elements for the benefit of the customer but this has obvious disadvantages that make this not an option.

You can of course view the Overprint Preview in acrobat with Output Preview in Print Production. This is fine if you only view this on a computer. To print in the print dialog box click Advanced then click simulate overprint.

[image]

[image]

You could set Overprint and Transparency Flattener Options to Preserve Overprints. However this requires PDF 1.3 only and will disable some editing features when the document is read back in. This is undesired.

[image]

Are there any other methods to obtain these results without causing breakout?

This is not a requirement for the answer, but preferably a method that does not require the customer to change any settings in their Acrobat if possible.

Comment: ..."*when sending a copy to the customer as a PDF it only shows the black layer because there is no overprint preview.*"... only if the customer is not using an Adobe product to view the PDF and has not adjusted preferences to show overprint preview *always*. I tend to try and educate my clients when this occurs. So, it's a one-time issue.

Comment: And you could, of course, adjust the job options when creating the PDF.

Comment: @Scott I've found that changing those options in CC 2017 will cause editing issues if it is read back in.

Comment: Why would you read the PDF "back in"??? You mean you work on and save to PDF only? You don't retain the Illustrator file and work on that?

Comment: @Scott The customer works only from PDF and requires artwork to be sent in PDF format. They won't accept a PDF that has limited editing capabilities.

Comment: Okay... "*They won't accept a PDF that has limited editing capabilities*" Then they should be taught about overprint preview if they intend to edit PDFs. To be honest, I'm really not getting the overall workflow. If they want editing capabilities, seems .ai files would be better.

Comment: @Scott  I can work around the overprint issue. The main focus of this question is different methods of creating a gradient without breakout. To answer your question about workflow, the customer always sends the initial artwork in PDF format and they want it back in PDF format so their art team can manipulate it.

Comment: Okay. if you can't alter PDF settings, I'm afraid there may not be a viable solution. The only real way to get around the horrible greys due to blending is to not use spot colors or stack the colors as you are (or rasterize, but we both know that sucks). At least those are the only method I'm aware of. Hopefully someone will post something new to me. Sorry. I really wasn't trying to be argumentative at all. I know I can come across that way at times. Not my intention in the least.

Comment: @Scott No problem :) I don't know why they are not willing to accept Illustrator format. My speculation is it must go through a lot of hands that do not have Illustrator. Perhaps non-tech savvy management established this workflow and is unwilling to change. Instead of educating all departments, they instruct their art team to only use PDF to keep things in their opinion "simpler" and not have 2 formats floating around. That's my guess. Either way I've found this workflow common in this particular industry. Everything mostly comes in as PDF and they want PDF. I don't try to fight it anymore.